# How to create a layout for a special device?

Tags: android, eclipse

To support the multiple screen sizes I work with res> layout-small, layout-normal, layout-large, layout-xlarge. But how does it work, if I want to have a layout for a special device. In my case I want to create a layout only for  the 3,7" (480x854: hdpi) device. How does that work?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android UI Design: Supporting Multiple Screens](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345115/android-ui-design-supporting-multiple-screens)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can control it using "Screen size" qualifier but notice that it is available from API level 13 (Android 3.2) and above while screen size groups (small/medium/...etc) are available or supported in all devices ...

Under "res" directory, simply add a directory named as "layout-sw480dp-h854dp"

For details on resource device characteristics see "http://bit.ly/DeviceDifferences"

Comment: If I do so, it shows me "Failed to create the part's controls" ?!

Comment: this is related to eclipse itself, chk this http://stackoverflow.com/a/14403152/1334561 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14280402/failed-to-create-the-parts-controls-in-eclipse-with-salesforce